# Database Design for a social networking website using mysql (just guidance)

Tags: mysql, database, schema, social-networking

I have went through other similar posts here but did not find answer for what I am looking. I am really not good with databases and presently working on a kind of social networking website project.

Taking in consideration that my website have at least 1 million subscribers and I am using mySQL

And my website contains functionality of like both facebook and linkedin, a mix of both in a professional manner. I mean removing more social things of facebook and more professional things of linkedin.

I just want a guidance of how to design databases for such a website. I do not want to dive in normalizations or linking tables. I just want to know how many databases are required for it and what kind of basic tables should it contain.

I thought of creating a main database which contains tables which is of administrative purpose and create a separate database for each user which contains all the tables that hold his data or creating a single database with table names starting with id of user to identify. But I seriously think it is a very bad design.

Kindly help with some tips or anything.

Comment: For a complex site such as you describe, with as many users as you hope for, you will have to get up to scratch with DB design... why do you think you might need 2 separate databases?

Comment: I don't know, I never designed a database for such a complex system. That is why seeking guidance in making one.

Comment: My tip would be to hire someone who knows about databases to design your million user system, and then try and learn about database design on a smaller project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have so many subscribers it's better to use Oracle or SQL Server for database and not MySQL my opinion.

Read this it will help you a lot  http://www.gplivna.eu/papers/choose_database.htm how to choose the right one for you.

Read this http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/  learn the common mistakes and avoid them.

Comment: I went through them, it is helpful, but it did not answered my question